# When refering to 2 people, do you use "have" or "has"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Example -

> If you or Theresa **has** time, let me know.
>   If you or Theresa **have** time, let me know.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The subject is singular - it's either Tom or Theresa. The verb form usually depends on the principle of proximity:

*If you or Theresa has time ...*

*If Theresa or you have time ...*

Comment: This is one of those rule exceptions. and in this case you shouldn't use the proximity rule

Answer (score 0):

I believe, since you are addressing "you", then the 2nd person case would be correct.

If you have time, let me know.
If you or Theresa have time, let me know.